# RaspAp only working in ssh

Tags: raspbian, ssh

I set up RaspAP through ssh to get it up and running but every time I end the ssh connection from my pc the hotspot stops working. I'm new to this so anything helps. I don't know if its something I messed up or if its something with RaspAP itself.

Comment: Assuming you are starting it from your SSH session, unless you start it in the background or use something like screen or tmux, it will end when the SSH connection is closed.

Comment: i ssh into my pi 3 and installed raspap through terminal. i wasnt using a remote desktop conection